# How to make a google login account for my own site thats like the one of StackOverflow?

Tags: authentication, google-openid

I would like to make a gmail open id login account for my site.

I googled around for it, but wasn't sure what I really need out of all the google products.  Any suggestions/advice on how to get started would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: what platform are you using? php, java, rails, django, etc.?

Comment: http://openid.net/developers/ ???

Comment: @Kevin I am using php, but a JS solution would work just as well. Thanks.

Comment: @JFFF not usre I want OpenId because it doesn't have as wide of an adoption....unless....can people log into it with their gmail credentials?

Comment: @GeekedOut Yes they can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries

http://openid.net/

You will find some valuable information on these sites. OpenID.net contains examples of how people have implemented it and will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow use the openID platform... Pretty straightforward for adding to your site. http://openid.net/add-openid/.

Google, Yahoo, etc. have interfaces into OpenID

http://openid.net/developer/. section is for developing your own interface to be used by OpenID